# Issue with PyQt GUI not updating export_text properly

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a PyQt-based GUI where I'm using the `add_text` function to add text to the GUI and update the `export_text` attribute. However, when I delete lines in the GUI, the deleted lines still appear in the exported TXT file. I've checked the `delete` function, and it seems to be working as expected. Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
def **init**(self):
super().**init**()

```
    self.export_text = ""
    self.initUI()

def clear_text(self):
    self.text_edit.clear()
    self.export_text = ""

def add_text(self, text):
    excluded_prefixes = ("set", "wait", "call")

    if not text.startswith(excluded_prefixes):
        cursor = self.text_edit.textCursor()
        cursor.insertText(text)

    
    self.export_text += text if text.startswith(excluded_prefixes) else ""

def save_text(self):
    file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Esporta", "", "File Kairos (*.txt)")
    if file_name:
        with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
            file.write(self.export_text)


def create_word_file(self):
    file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Salva file", "", "File Word (*.docx)")
    if file_name:
        text = self.text_edit.toPlainText()
        filtered_text = "\n".join(line.strip()[2:] for line in text.splitlines() if line.strip().startswith("--"))

        document = Document()

        # Aggiungi un paragrafo per ogni riga di testo filtrata
        for line in filtered_text.split("\n"):
            paragraph = document.add_paragraph(line)

        document.save(file_name)

def load_text(self):
    file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Carica", "", "File Kairos (*.txt)")
    if file_name:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
            text = file.read()
            self.text_edit.setPlainText(text)
```

I tried a bunch of stuff to figure out what's going on:

I dug into my delete function. Looks like it's doing its job, removing lines from the GUI when I delete them.